# Gave permission to READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, but still get exception java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I'm trying to store and open image, which is taken from device storage (Photo made by Camera);

Inside session I can open this image by `imgg.setImageURI(uri1);`, but after session is over and new one is up I get exception :

> ava.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider
> com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from
> ProcessRecord{3964df7 21535:com.example.myapplication/u0a121}
> (pid=21535, uid=10121) requires that you obtain access using
> ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs.

I've searched internet, tried a lot of different solutions and no one solved my problem.

For clarity, i added:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:ignore="ScopedStorage"/>
```

in AndroidManifest.xml

then I added:

```java
String[] permissionsStorage = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        int requestExternalStorage = 1;
        int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissionsStorage, requestExternalStorage);
        }
```

in my onCreate function.

On the next run application asked me for permission, i clicked "ok" and permission seems to be set to "true", but it not solve my problem.

After trying some other solutions (this one was not the first attempt), i've checked permissions inside of virtual devices and there my application have all the permissions.

But exception is still here.

How to handle it (i've read like 10 articles, which not help)?
Is there any common solution im blind for?

intent creation:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);

                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "???");
                intent.setType("image/*");

                someActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
                //ActivityResultContracts pew = new ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument();
                //Intent intent = new Intent();
                //mGetContent.launch("image/*");


            }
        });
```

intent process:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        // There are no request codes
                        final int takeFlags = intent.getFlags() & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                                | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                        Intent data = result.getData();

                        String FilePath = data.getData().getPath();
                        Uri uri = data.getData();
                        ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
                        contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags);
                        //contentResolver.releasePersistableUriPermission(uri,takeFlags);
                        Intent data2 = result.getData();
                        FILE_ADRESS=uri;
                        imgg.setImageURI(FILE_ADRESS);
                        FILE_PATH=FILE_ADRESS.getPath();
                    }
                }
            });
```

exception is here:

```
final Uri uri1 = Uri.parse(str_address);


        if (str_address!=null & str_address.length()>0) {
           
            final Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(str_address);
            imgg.setImageURI(null);
            imgg.setImageURI(uri1);


        }
```

All the permissions are gived (programmatically and also manually in device settings)

Comment: Where are you getting the `Uri` value from? Your code above gets it via `String str_address=getArguments().getString("Uri");`, but where did the original value come from that was stored in the argument?

Comment: the Uri is fine, it stored when the image is first time uploaded from the system. Is not a problem of Uri (i've tested it the whole day already). Please read the error message, it clearly says that is access problem (security exception - permission denial)

Comment: "it stored when the image is first time uploaded from the system" -- that likely is your problem. Most `Uri` values cannot be stored, because [your access rights to the content end after a short period of time](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html). This is why I asked where you are getting your `Uri` from.

Comment: Okay, you asked, i will answer. I take a image from system and store it URI inside of a string variable that is saved in the inner .txt document. Upon loading app takes this .txt file and draws a button for each item stored inside. The item consist of name--+Uri and may have another info later (once i stabilish this part). So, upon loading it takes all the stored URI items and draw a btn that gives access to item. Upon first load of item - it works fine, i can open it fine. But after app reload - access denied. Tryied already a 5-10 methods, but found not solution.

Comment: Okay, that is not a point im stick in. If you have a proper solution that will work fine, as for example to store path or something - i will be happy to use that. The problem is that when i try to use `uri.getPath();` and then make a drawable - it returns null for the very same reason - access deny (or maybe wrong adress or name - i've tryied them all - nothing works).

Comment: "that is not a point im stick in" -- yes, it is, based on your error message. "But after app reload - access denied" -- that is because [your access rights to the content end after a short period of time](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html), including immediately upon the end of your process. Use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and `takePersistableUriPermissions()`, as is covered in [that blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html).

Comment: im sorry, but this does not solves any problem of mine, because -- there is no examples of code. I have no ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT in my code and till the moment i do not understand how to use it and how to change my code. If you really want to help me - please, give me example of code or something like that. 
Currently i call item upload from fragment with onResult code. How do i change on ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT and how to use takePersistableUriPermission(). 

By the way storing uri.getPath() not works

Comment: @CommonsWare 

What this supposed to mean: 
`try using takePersistableUriPermissions() on ContentResolver to get long-term access to the content.`
Okay, the func, but how to work with contentResolvere?! This blows up my mind really.

Comment: "I have no ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT in my code" -- if you wish to persist the `Uri`, you will need to switch to using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` (or the `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument` wrapper). See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider), [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases), and [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files).

Comment: See also [this blog post series](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/19/scoped-storage-stories-saf-basics.html) and [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-content-001.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack).

Comment: @CommonsWare after spending some time modifying my code i made it based on intentions and tried to use all my new knowledge based on your advices, and everything just to face the same problem as before - ava.lang.SecurityException: `Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{edede0e 10058:com.example.myapplication/u0a121} (pid=10058, uid=10121) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs`

Any ideas?

Comment: You do not need any permission to use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT. So please remove all irrelevant code. After that show how you use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT and the obtained uri.

Comment: @blackapps i've already done with this by ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, is based on this mechanic at the moment. I open item by intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);, it shows me window to select image, and after that works well - i catch result, store URI, etc. But after app reload i get exception on permission. How can i use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT without actually opening window and selecting it? Is there such an option? By using the same URI i got from previous launches.

Comment: "i catch result, store URI, etc." -- did you [call `takePersistableUriPermissions()` on a `ContentResolver`](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#java) as soon as you get the `Uri`?

Comment: Post complete code in your post. Not in a comment. Remove the irrelevant code as asked before.

Comment: updated post as requested. 

Problem still here, yes, i use takePersistableUriPermission and tryied also releasePersistableUriPermission.. still no work.

Comment: I've noted that takeFlag returns = '0'. Possible there is a problem? Or no? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Finally the problem was in flags which return 0;
Added `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);` in Intention initialization and things worked well. Damn this took me the whole day to figure out.

Hope will help someone and save precious time! Thanks everyone responding! :3